# Makefile: writing filtering outputs to separate files

Tags: shell, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile that compares a list of entries, against one column of another file and if they match I want to make separate files for each entry. Meaning that if entry number 1 with name "AAA" is found in a column, the whole row of that column is printed to a file called "AAA.txt". I have written a code like this:

```
INPUT_DIR = inputs
OUTPUT_DIR = outputs
ENTRY_DIR = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/entry
FILTER_FILE = $(INPUT_DIR)/data.txt

ENTRY_LIST_FILE = $(wildcard inputs/entries.txt)
DATA_FILTERED_FILES = $(ENTRY_LIST:%=$(ENTRY_DIR)/%.txt)

all: $(DATA_FILTERED_FILES)

$(ENTRY_DIR)/%.txt:
    @while read line; do \
        while read row; do \
            columns=($$row); \
            if [ "$$line" == "$${columns[7]}" ]; then \
                echo "$$row" >> $@; \
            fi; \
        done < $(FILTER_FILE); \
    done < $(ENTRY_LIST_FILE)
```

The problem I am having is that it filters okay, but all the outputs are the same. File AAA.txt also has rows that have other entries from the list (for example AAB). I want to separate these files (so have one called AAA.txt, that only has rows that have AAA in 8th column, and AAB.txt that only has rows that contain AAB in their 8th column.

Is there a way to make separate files for all entries? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I find the text of your question unintelligible. I'm sure *you* know what you mean, but... could you give us an example? An actual example, a couple of small files and what you want Make to do with them.

Comment: Actually I solved it in these 2 hours so no worries. Sorry if it was unclear. But now I have a different question, maybe you could answer here as well. I was writing this makefile on my MacBook Pro using XCode and executing via built-in Terminal. Now I moved this makefile to server that I am working on, and for some reason it gives me an error:
"/bin/sh: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")
make: *** [makefile:15: gene_files] Error 2"
I know its a syntax error, but I don't get why on my laptop it works fine but on server it is not working.

Comment: Try executing the shell command on your MacBook and on the server, and see how they compare.

Comment: Just because you want to make files does not mean that `make` is an appropriate tool for the job.  You can do anything with `make` that you can do with shell commands, but the tasks that are actually *eased* by application of `make` (or any other build tool) are a considerably smaller set.

Comment: Adding a comment here will reach a preciously small number of people. If you have a new question, post a new question (and post an answer to this one and mark it as accepted once you can to mark this one as resolved).

Comment: (... Or just delete this question; but understand that _repeatedly_ asking and then deleting might not be well received by the community.)

Comment: The reason for the error you're getting is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652868/939557